# Non linear transformation of the feature for Radial Svm

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

Here's my question:

I have a medium size data set about the condition of a hydraulic system.

The data set is represented by 68 variables plus condition of the system(green, yellow, red)

I have to use several classifiers to predict the behavior of the system so I have divided my data set into training and test set and normalize them.

In particular I'm using a Radial Svm.

I know that the idea behind generating non linear decision boundaries is that we need to do some non linear transformations on the features which transforms them to a higher dimensional space. We do this non linear transformation using the Kernel trick.

I wrote:

```
reg_Control = trainControl("repeatedcv", number = 5, repeats=5, verboseIter = T, classProbs =T)
    svmRGrid=expand.grid(sigma=seq(0.00003,0.00009,0.00003),C=seq(0.03,0.06,0.03))

svmRadial = train(Condition ~.,data=training_norm, method="svmRadial", trControl=reg_Control,tuneGrid=svmRGrid)
```

My problem is..

How do I do the non linear transformation on the feature to transform them to a higher dimensional space??

Is what I wrote enough??

(Does the method SvmRadial do the non linear transformation itself?)

I have to make a comparison with other classifiers so I'm trying different values for sigma and C with the RadialSvm and confronting the results so selecting those with the best performance, is it right??

A step by step answer with some code would be of great help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to this one. Yes! When you specify radial kernels with the caret package it will transform the data into a higher dimensional subspace for you.

Take a look at this thread on statexchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10551/how-do-i-choose-what-svm-kernels-to-use

Comment: Many thanks for your answer@Ollie Perkins! Now I'm confronting several values for C and Sigma and checking their performance on the testing set, then I will choose the best ones.  Do I have to consider also the performance of the different classifiers by typing their name on the console to have an exhaustive answer?

Comment: Yes, though you can find the optimum values for C and Sigma on the training set by trialling many values using a custom training grid in caret, which you pass to the train.control argument. If my answer is correct, then please accept and upvote.

Comment: See - https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#custom